# php if statement i need to echo class base on the string given by custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin in my WordPress theme, to use custom fields in the post area.

I want to change the class of a `<span>` depending on the status of a field, but it isn't working as expected. For instance, when the status is set to `new`, I want `<span class="status">`, but with the following code this isn't happening:

```
<?php
echo "<span ";

if(the_field('status') == "new") {
  echo "class=\"status\"";
} else {
  echo "class=\"statusSold\"";
}

echo ">";
the_field('status');
echo "</span>";
?>
```

This is the whole script:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
  );
  $the_query = new WP_Query($args);

  if ($the_query->have_posts()):
    while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
?>

<li>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
    <span class="hover">&nbsp;</span>
    <?php
      $class = the_field('status') == 'new' ? 'status' : 'statusSold';
      echo '<span class="' . $class . '">' . the_field('status') . '</span>';
    ?>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) the_post_thumbnail('post-thumbnails'); ?>
    <span class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
    <span class="type"><?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {echo $category->cat_name; } ?></span>
    <span class="address"><?php the_field('address'); ?></span>
    <span class="prize"><?php the_field('price'); ?></span>
  </a>
</li>

<?php
    endwhile;
  endif;
?>
```

**What must I do to make this work as expected?**

Comment: I want to echo `class` base on the `string` input in Custom Fields if(new){echo "class="status"";} else {echo "class="statusSold"";}

Comment: And what do you get instead?

Comment: Yes, but what is the problem with your current attempt? I assume it's not working. What is happening?

Comment: the output of what I try is this `<span new>new</span>`

Comment: Are you sure you past the correct code ? Assuming the_field() is known and not bugged, the code I see should work.

Comment: I don't think the downvotes and close votes are quite fair here. People who understand advanced custom fields (and wordpress) way of working with variables or printing them will understand the simple problem that is going on here.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it a little more obvious what you were asking for the sake of people finding this in the future

Comment: Pleasure, I'm sure your next question will be able to use this one to help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really tell what is wrong with your current attempt - but it is messy. Try this instead:

```
$class = the_field('status') == 'new' ? 'status' : 'statusSold';

echo '<span class="' . $class . '">' . the_field('status') . '</span>';
```

This should do what you want it to do. [Check out this demo.](http://codepad.org/qvZvbFJi) If this doesn't work, then the problem is something else - most likely to do with `the_field('status')`. If more debugging is necessary. Try simply echoing `the_field('status')` to confirm that it is returning the appropriate response.

---

*Update*

The problem is that your function, `the_field()`, does not return a value, it simply echos it. [**Consider this demo to mimic your problem**](http://codepad.org/HvCg7YSd). <del>I'd say the best way to fix this would be to overload the function to return a value. However,</del> Here is a pretty hacky fix that should work for you ***(Edit: This is probably not the best approach, See update 2 and @LeonardChallis's answer. That is probably the solution you need)***:

```
echo '<span style="display:none">';
$class = strcmp(the_field('status'), 'new') ? 'status' : 'statusSold';
echo '</span>';

echo '<span class="' . $class . '">';
the_field('status');
echo '</span>';
```

---

*Update 2*

Or, better yet, use the appropriate function. According to @LeonardChallis, that function is `get_field()`.

Comment: thank's for your answer but this is the result `soldsold<span class="statusSold"></span>`

Comment: Ok, I get it. `the_field()` does not return anything then, it echos. See [this demo](http://codepad.org/HvCg7YSd) that mimics your problem. Can you change `the_field()` function to return instead of echo?

Comment: Don't edit/overload the function - there is provided functionality in the documentation that provides what you need! See my answer for more info and links.

Comment: thank's for your help your code and @LeonardChallis opinion make it work's thank you cheers

Comment: @LeonardChallis You're right. I have updated my answer. +1

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `the_field()` echo's (prints to screen) the content. You should instead use `get_field()`. This is explained in the basics documentation (see: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started/displaying-custom-field-values-in-your-theme/). For more information on `get_field()`, complete with examples, see http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/get_field/